# Visual studio 2013 not hitting breakpoints in a referenced project in debug

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, task, breakpoints

I have two solutions, one is my main app and the other is a plugin. I am editing the plugin for my app so I have added the plugins project to my apps solution and referenced it instead of the .dll

I am having problems with the breakpoints in the plugin. I have put some breakpoints where the plugin is waiting for a response. The plugin fires off an event once it has processed the data and my main app is subscribed to the event. The debugger always breaks on the event in the main app but in my plugin the debugger will only hit the breakpoints when I first start of the program. When the breakpoints aren't hit I look at the call stack and it shows me that it has gone past that piece of code with the breakpoint in.

I have no idea what is going on here and it has only just started happening. The last thing that I did was add a task into the plugin which would go off and process results when it has received the data.

Can anyone help me?

My code is running in debug

*UPDATE*

Basically my problem is I am getting data from a list of objects and am getting one, then processing it in my Task while I get another. This was working fine however when the issue with the break points started I noticed that the data that was being return was exactly the same all the time and is always the first element that I get.

I don't know whether that is of any use or not but it may be a caching problem that I can't identify.

Comment: How do you initialise your plugins? Assembly.Load()? ComponentModel? (In fact i think it doesnt matter, I dont think debugger is attached in any of this cases... Try to just reference your plugin for testing purposes ;) )

Comment: When I say plugin I mean something which allows me to talk to another app of ours. So we just have a using statement. We use nuGet so if we make changes to the plugin we have to check it in, build it and then deploy the package to nuGet so generally whenever we are constantly editing code inside the plugin project we just add the project to our solution.

Comment: FYI I added some more information into my post just in case that gives you any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to put a Debugger.Launch() statement in place of a breakpoint. I have had to use this many times when debugging applications that I don't control the application start and need more of a remote debugging scenario. The Debugger.Launch() will allow you to attach a new or existing VS instance to a running application.

By doing that in your scenario, you can start to inspect the threads (both in your current VS, and any new VS you attach with the Debugger.Launch() to ensure that they are both aware of the same threads. Your original VS may be losing access to the threads that your callback are on and thereby is unable to break.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's really useful thanks. I have since managed to track down the source of the problem and it looks like one of our other dlls is throwing a few errors which are getting lost in the threads. I am going to mark this answer as the correct answer as it would have helped me if I hadn't noticed the output window.